# Example of a differentiable function optimization where derivative free methods are used

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, derivations

While preparing a workshop on the derivative free methods, and fminsearch in MATLAB, I found an example function where fminsearch converges better and in less iterations than fmincon with calculated derivatives. Since fminsearch uses Nelder-Mead method, I suppose it would do a better job in terms of optimization, when a function has a lot of variables, but is quadratic.

Do you happen to know any concrete examples of a function or a class of differentiable functions where calculating the derivatives doesn't help optimization-wise?

Any answer would be really useful.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose one general situation where Nelder-Mead might perform better is when the objective function is 'simple' at the length scale of the initial simplex, but is very oscillatory at the 'microscopic' scale; in this sort of situation, Nelder-Mead won't 'see' the complicated local behaviour, whereas a derivative-based method could be confused and impeded by it.

For a concrete example on the real line, I had a play at finding the global minimum of $x\longmapsto x^2 + \sin(1000 x)$ with different initial conditions and marked the minima found by Nelder-Mead (blue dot) and BFGS (orange dot).

[image]

Zooming in to look at what went wrong for BFGS, it seems pretty likely that it's been thwarted by the 'microscopic' oscillations:

[image]

I've included the Python 3 code used to generate the plots in case that's helpful. The script below receives an `amplitude` and a `wavelength` as positional arguments when run from the command-line.

```
"""
Script for illustrating one situation when derivative-based optimisation methods can get into trouble.
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Read inputs from command line
amplitude = float(sys.argv[3])  # e.g. 1.0
wavelength = float(sys.argv[4])  # e.g. 1.0e-3

# Set up objective function and its derivative
objective = lambda x: np.square(x) + amplitude * np.sin(x / wavelength)
derivative = lambda x: 2 * x + (amplitude / wavelength) * np.cos(x / wavelength)

# Set up a starting position and a large initial simplex
starting_position = 100
initial_simplex_length = 10
initial_simplex = np.array([
    [starting_position],
    [starting_position + initial_simplex_length]
])

# Minimise using NM
results = {}
results["Nelder-Mead"] = minimize(
    objective,
    starting_position,
    method="Nelder-Mead",
    options={
        "initial_simplex": initial_simplex
    }
)

# Minimise using BFGS
results["BFGS"] = minimize(
    objective,
    starting_position,
    method="BFGS",
    jac=derivative
)

# Initialise plot
_, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot objective function
xs = np.arange(-0.2 * starting_position, 1.2 * starting_position, 0.5 * wavelength)
ax.plot(xs, objective(xs))

# Mark minima found by both methods
for method, result in results.items():
    ax.scatter(
        [np.squeeze(result.x)],
        [result.fun],
        label=method
    )

ax.legend()
ax.set_title(
    f"Nelder-Mead vs BFGS on x^2 + {amplitude} sin(x / {wavelength})\n"
    f"with x0 = {starting_position}, initial_simplex = {np.squeeze(initial_simplex)}"
)
plt.show()

# Print results
print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed anwser. I understand your point when discussing the problem of finding a global minimum, whereas BFGS gets stuck in local minimum.
However, both fminsearch and fminunc are meant to find local minima, and therefor, this example only shows the huge disadvantage toward the Nelder-Mead.

Comment: I take your point. However, it's possible to come up with similar examples where - instead of small oscillation - the objective function has lots of short flat sections (rather than a wiggly parabola like the one above, maybe think of a 'staircase with rounded corners').